# Holomorphic function on simply connected set with large derivative is injective?

Tags: complex-analysis

I am wondering if it's true that for a simple connected/convex/disc $U$, whenever we have holormophic $f:U\to \mathbb C$ with $|f'(z)|>M$ for all $z$ ($M>0$),  $f$ is injective.

Note that $z\mapsto z^2$ in the exterior of the unit disc has this property, but it is not injective, so simple connectedness seems required for this to hold.

Clearly, if $U=\mathbb C$ then $1/f'$ is bounded so it is constant, and $f$ is linear.

If we have additional conditions on $f'$, such as $\Re f'>M$, then the $f$ is necessarily injective (Integral form of the Mean Value Theorem)

Answer (score 1):

No, it is false even with convex hypothesis on domain : take $f(z)=e^z$ on $-1\lt \Re(z)\lt 1 $.